# flutter get data from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the average of a number from Firestore. I stored the data as a `number`.

```
class Rating{

  double sum = 0;
  int? sumList = 0;



 //First I get the total sum of numbers in the collection. This returns the sum of all the items in the field "Stars".
Future<double> getSumRating() async {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("userCollection")
              .doc(doc)
              .collection("ratingCollecion")
              .get()
              .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
                    sum += element.get("Stars");
                  }));
          return sum;
        }

//Then I get the total list of items in that collection. This returns the number of documents in the collection.
  Future<int> getListCount() async {
          var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("userCollection")
              .doc(doc)
              .collection("ratingCollecion")
              .get();
          return snapshot.docs.length;
        }



//Then for the UI
  rating(){
       return Column(children: [
 //I called Future Builder for both the sum and the List                         
FutureBuilder(future:getSumRating(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                       if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                         return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return const Text('Error');
                                } else {
                                  return Text("$sum");
                                }
                              },
                            ),//it works
                          
 FutureBuilder(future: getListCount(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                   if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                     return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                         } 
                        else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return const Text('Error');
                         } 
                         else {
                             sumList = snapshot.data;
                             return Text("$sumList");
                                }
                              },
                            ),//it also works
                                ]
                      );
          }

}
```

Everything works for both `sum` and `sumList`. But I don't know how to get the average.
I tried this but didn't work

```
sumofList = sumList!.toDouble
final average = sum / sumofList; //this gives me  I/flutter ( 5105): NaN when I print it.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Most likely your doing `final average = sum / sumList;` before `sum` has been set. Can you edit your question to show how these three code snippets relate to eachother?

Comment: Need more clarity on your code, please. I am trying to understand the data flow like how are you calling your functions, and in what order? also, try to add print statements at every future call. This would show you if you are getting Data on the specific step for the value of Sum and Length. mostly. also, make sure you are `awaiting` on the future call, as if you won't `await` the value is mostly going to be null. Here is some docs on how to handle futures properly: `https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-using-futures-in-flutter-for-beginners-ebeddfbfb967`.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check and see if you can help

Answer (score 0):

Use counter variable to count each iteration of loop to get total number of items and calculate through formula or also you can use simple for loop for counting items instead of foreach loop.